# Why is my TensorFlow model detecting entire frame as item?

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I am using [tensorflows model maker](https://colab.research.google.com/github/khanhlvg/tflite_raspberry_pi/blob/main/object_detection/Train_custom_model_tutorial.ipynb) following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ZyFYniGUsw) and when I run the program I get the following results from the images below. The Average precision I get from the model maker is 86% so I am unsure why the results are so bad. What could be causing this?

Here is also a link to the [github that contains the training data](https://github.com/priedejm/shirts/tree/main). Shirts.zip contains the train and validate folders.

[image]
[image]